# Authenticating Users using AfNetworking

Tags: ios7, afnetworking

I'm trying to authenticate users, but my app keeps on crashing with error 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: urlRequest' what am I doing wrong?

Below is my code

```
  -(IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender
{

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"email": email.text, @"pass": pword.text};

NSString *str = @"http://www.blablablabla/api2/user.php?type=login";
str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:str parameters:parameters];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
//[operation setCredential:credential];
[operation setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer alloc]];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
}];
    [manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be alloc-ing the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager but does it ever get init'ed?

Also, check the request for nil before passing it to the AFHTTPRequestOperation.

Checking parameters and alloc'ed/created instances for nil can help you tell IMMEDIATELY where a problem is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You, it gave me a response after passing nil, but not passing the email and password even when I pass it in front of the parameters manually @nsdebug